# Return an element using `array.some()` instead of boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

I'm trying to use an `array.some` function to iterate through some data and return my `field` if the if statement succeeds.

What I am finding is happening instead, is that I am getting a boolean return e.g `true` instead of the actual variable (which contains details to an element).

```
for (var index in allFields) {
      const invalidField = allFields[index].some(function (field){
        if (!validation.getIn([index,field.dataset.fieldKey,'isValid'])) {
          return field;
        }
      });
      if (invalidField) {
        return invalidField;
      }
    }
```

My code cycles through `allFields`, which contains lists of fields under indexes. It then compares each `fieldKey` with another set of data called `validation`.

`field` contains an element. I wish to return `field` but instead when I check `invalidField` I get `true` instead of the element

Comment: `some` returns a boolean value and if `true`, it ends the iteration.

Comment: `array.some` is doing as designed. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) `array.find()` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) may be more what you want

Comment: Your confusion here might be that you are returning `field` which is the element you want from your callback, but that's not what `some` returns. Per [msn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for the return value: `true if the callback function returns a truthy value for any array element; otherwise, false.` `field` is "truthy", so `some` returns `true`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Array.prototype.some()` only checks if any element in the array passes test defined in callback function. You should use array `find` method which returns first element passig test

Comment: Just note that `find` return an item from the array if matched. Or `undefined` otherwise, so it's better to check if it returned `undefined` before attempting to use that returned value.

Comment: Wish there were something like `find()` but to be able to return something custom instead of just the element.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Filter does what you're currently expecting `some()` to do. `some()` returns a boolean if 1 or more elements meet your criteria while `filter()` creates a new array of elements that met your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

to get the element, you need to use `array.filter()`

```
for (var index in allFields) {
  const invalidField = allFields[index].filter(function (field){
    if (!validation.getIn([index,field.dataset.fieldKey,'isValid'])) {
      return field;
    }
  });
  if (invalidField.length > 0) { //check if returned anything
    return invalidField[0];
  }
}
```

If you want to return only the first, you can use `array.find()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find